# React App Axios firing twice -- No CORS, No Strict Mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am having an odd issue that I cannot get past.  My AJAX call via AXIOS is being called twice.  I have read extensively, and even when I find "like" issues, Mine isn't solvable by using the answers on those posts, either because I am not using the methods they are, or because I am not using CROSS ORIGIN.  I am also not using Strict Mode.  I seriously am at a loss here!

```
root.render(
  //<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  //</React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = {
            name: event.target.elements.name.value
        };

        axios.post(`/api/v2/users/add`, {data})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data.user['name']);
            })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Person Name:
                        <input type="text" name="name"/>
                    </label>
                    <button type="submit">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The event fires twice.  The first time it SENDS the payload .. The second time it RECEIVES the response.  This is so strange!  I have tried everything I know how.  I have tried setting a state `onChange()` instead of statically setting the "name" field: `name: event.target.elements.name.value`.  This is a basic 30 line app ..  I really don't know what to look at next.  Am I missing something glaring?

[image]
[image]

To be clear I have read the following posts and NONE are an answer to my question:

[Every axios request firing twice in react-redux app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787719/every-axios-request-firing-twice-in-react-redux-app) (I am not using Cross Origin.)

[Events firing twice inside axios interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031780/events-firing-twice-inside-axios-interceptor) (Read this thinking maybe .. But not my issue)

[React and Axios fires twice (once undefined, once successfully)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261284/react-and-axios-fires-twice-once-undefined-once-successfully)  (Not Changing State)

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you are using URL "directory" based APIs if you don't include the trailing slash, you will get a 301 redirect, with WILL NOT re-post your data .. So the Payload expires on the first trip, then the redirect receives NO payload, but gets the correct response MINUS the payloads parameters.

There IS a difference between

```
/api/v2/users/add
```

and

```
/api/v2/users/add/
```

Comment: The 301 is entirely server dependent